# Authentification in the webView QML

Tags: c++, qt, webkit, qml, qtwebkit

I am trying to use webkit to display web pages in qml, except I can not find the syntax to access a page that contains a login and password

Here is a snippet of code :

```
 Rectangle {
   id: webBrowser
   property string urlString : "http://website.com/"
   //
 }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To authenticate http requests, connect `viewer.engine()->networkAccessManager()` [authenticationRequired](http://qt-project.org/doc/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#authenticationRequired) signal to your slot where you can set `QAuthenticator` name and password fields.

Comment: I have my doubts if this answer is true for  the QML WebView using native WebViews on Windows (IWebView) and Mac (WkWebView). As far as I understand the implementation each of those widgets uses the system HTTP stack and neither in the windows implementation (qwinrtwebview.cpp) nor in the mac implementation (qdarwinwebview.mm) signals specific to authentication are emitted.